# login control not working in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.5

I'm trying to study ios coding myself I'm creating a testing app which contain a login page and a welcome screen I'm using storyboard and the entire layout and functionalities are completed but I'm stuck with a problem . I need to move from login view to the welcome view after successful login and if the login failed it will show an error message everything is working fine except the login failed scenario when the login attempt failed not only shows the error message but also move to the welcome view. My current code is given below

```
if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
{
    responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webServiceData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
    NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",success);
    if(success == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Login Success");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"LoginSucceeded" sender:self];

    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"Login Failed");
        [txtPassword setText:@""];
        [txtUser setText:@""];
        [self alertStatus:@"Username and/or password is invalid." :@"Login Failed"];
    }

}
else
{
    [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
}
```

I cant find out whats the reason behind this problem. Please point out the mistake.

Comment: Where are you running that code? What method is it part of?

Comment: What code paths in this method were executed, with which corresponding server responses, when you ran this through the debugger?

Comment: I'm running this method when the login button is clicked

Comment: May be you have connected the welcome view with login button in storyboard also. So it is moving to next

Comment: @GopeshGupta oh What a Fool I'm I didnt think that before thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @GopeshGupta Yep its Working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't Connect the view in storyboard if you are performing some operation. You can do like this in that case

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
FirstViewController *myVC = (FirstViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController1"];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Push or Present your view manually by doing this.